# Painting 100 random lines - increase size and speed?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

This code will generate random red lines that are very small very quickly. I need to only generate 100 lines and make them bigger and have a timer for 5 seconds. I am confused as to where the heck the size is.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class LinesRandom extends JPanel {

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.red);

     for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
        Dimension size = getSize();
        int w = size.width;
        int h = size.height;
        Random r = new Random();
        int x = (r.nextInt()) % w;
        int y = (r.nextInt()) % h;
        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
       repaint();
       }
     }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      LinesRandom points = new LinesRandom();
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Points");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(points);
      frame.setSize(500, 500);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: The size of a line is defined by its Stroke, look for BasicStroke. Don't call repaint inside your pain method, this is going to cause you no end of trouble. Instead, make Swing Timer and allow it to run until you have 100 lines - hint: you can't use a loop

Answer (score 2):

> I am confused as to where the heck the size is.

A lines size is defined by its stroke - See [Stroking and Filling Graphics Primitives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html) for more details

> I need to only generate 100 lines ... and have a timer for 5 seconds

The best solution is to use a Swing `Timer`, set with the required delay between updates.  The `Timer` acts as pseudo loop, so you will need to keep track of the number of times it's `ActionListener` is called and stop it when it reaches 100.

You'd then place the random `Point`s into some kind of `List` and when `paintComponent` is called, paint the lines between these points

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details